# How to solve tora issue of "object can not be described"

Tags: debugging, tora

in tora program when i press f4 to open any table this massage appear "Object TABLE_NAME (DB_USER) cannot be described",
please, how to solve.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are the issue:

- A user account only allows a successful login
- Permissions to view a table is granted by the table owner

Use a SELECT statement of the `ALL_OBJECTS` data dictionary view to see which tables you have access to:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS
```

Use the `DBA_TABLES` data dictionary view to see all tables:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_TABLES
```

**References**

- [Managing Security for Oracle Database Users](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/users.htm)
- [The Data Dictionary](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datadict.htm)
- [Catalog Views/Data Dictionary Views](http://tahiti.oracle.com/pls/db901/db901.catalog_views?remark=homepage)
- [Tables Data Dictionary Views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables014.htm#ADMIN01508)
- [Data Dictionary Translation Support](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/apc.htm)
- [ALL_OBJECTS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2005.htm)
- [Syntax for Schema Objects and Parts in SQL Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements009.htm)
- [torasql - knowhow:debugger](http://torasql.com/knowhow%3adebugger)
- [Granting Object Privileges on Behalf of the Object Owner](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admusers.htm#i1007837)
- [ALTER USER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4003.htm)
- [DBMS_DESCRIBE, 1 of 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a76936/dbms_des.htm)
- [DBMS_DESCRIBE, 2 of 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_descr2.htm)